# In C++, is a free function taking a struct as an argument faster than a class with a member function to do the same thing?

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization, struct, this

I am alluding to [Klaus Iglberger's timeless lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLDT1lDOsb4) here.  I have a (relatively) simple function that takes a single float as input and returns the result as another float.  The function needs a number of parameters, however, which have to be pre-computed (otherwise it's not fast at all).  The way I see it, I can either make a struct to hold the pre-computations and then feed that to a free function along with the argument of the function to approximate, or write a class to hold the pre-computations as private members with a public member function to perform the approximate calculation based on the argument of interest.

I'm not looking to delve into opinions, here.  Either approach is arguably as clean and leads to code that is as legible as the other.
Give the `fastApprox` member function a meaningful name that lets developers know what the approximation is all about, and then a call to the free function with the struct or a call to the class public function differ only in terms of the order in which the terms appear, one has a period and the other has a comma.

```
struct StrPrecomp {

  StrPrecomp(float alpha_in);

  float c0;
  float c1;
  float c2;
};

float fastApprox(const StrPrecomp s, float x) {
  return s.c0 + ((s.c1 + (s.c2 * x)) * x);
}

class ClsPrecomp {
public:
  ClsPrecomp(float alpha_in);

  float fastApprox(float x) {
    return c0 + ((c1 + (c2 * x)) * x);
  };

private:
  float c0;
  float c1;
  float c2;
};

int main() {
  StrPrecomp ms(0.5);
  ClsPrecomp mc(0.5);
  printf("Struct Result: %12.4f\n", fastApprox(ms, 0.7071));
  printf("Class  Result: %12.4f\n", mc.fastApprox(0.7071));
}
```

Which is better in terms of performance?  Klaus comes down on the side of free functions, owing to the `this` pointer implicit in those class member functions.  But is there really a distinction in *this* case?  Below I submit the struct to the free function by const value, which will look off to many C++ developers but is identical in speed in this case due to there being no `std::vector` or other copyable members underneath that coould result in a massive amount of sneaky deep-copying.  If I were to submit the struct by const reference, it would be a pointer in its own right and, I expect, no different in performance than the class de-referencing this->c0, etc. with every member.

Cheers, all.

Comment: You pass a struct copy, it can't be faster.

Comment: I expect the functions to be inlined with optimizations enabled. If so, compilers can easily remove the copy so the overhead is null. I strongly advise you to compare the assembly code in such a case.

Comment: By the way, note that a question can be downvoted for many different reasons and "showing research effort" is one of them (though I find pretty bad to downvote new-users' questions without any comments).

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from looking at the generated assembly.

Comment: Have you checked (and benchmarked) what the compiler generates for each version when optimization is enabled?

Comment: When you benchmark, try it again with `fastApprox(const StrPrecomp &s)` in the first option. I don't expect it to make much difference but I prefer the second approach on cosmetic grounds.

Answer (score 2):

As always for performance, you have to measure.

From [quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/zzq4IKsyUJAa0rHeRXsoIphioWw), for your example, free function call and method call give similar result.

BTW, intuitively, I would say that method is mostly a function with `this` at first argument, so similar to free function call.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should be able to basically generate the same code in the two cases.

Notice, though, that you haven't written two equivalent codes. For instance, since you've not declared `ClsPrecomp::fastApprox` as `const` the corresponding signature of the free function `fastApprox` would be

```cpp
float fastApprox(StrPrecomp& s, float x);
```

Furthermore, to compare how the two solution differ, you want to compile a translation unit that uses one or the other solution. Notice, however, that you can't just write a class in a cpp file, compile it and get anything out of it. If you do, you'll end up with nothing, basically, because you'd have no function you can link to other object files. One possiblity is two write two translation units both exposing a function (`work`, in my example) accepting an object of your class(es), and see what they are compiled to.

Something like this:

- [free function approach](https://godbolt.org/z/sPor5TGTz)

  ```cpp
  // in header
  struct StrPrecomp {

    StrPrecomp(float alpha_in);
    float c0;
    float c1;
    float c2;
  };

  float fastApprox(StrPrecomp& s, float x);

  void work(StrPrecomp& obj);

  // in cpp
  StrPrecomp::StrPrecomp(float alpha_in) {}

  float fastApprox(StrPrecomp& s, float x) {
      return x;
  }

  void work(StrPrecomp& obj) {
      fastApprox(obj, 3);
  }
  ```
- [member function approach](https://godbolt.org/z/3oacc1s96)

  ```cpp
  // in header
  class ClsPrecomp {
  public:
    ClsPrecomp(float alpha_in);

    float fastApprox(float x);

  private:
    float c0;
    float c1;
    float c2;
  };

  void work(ClsPrecomp& obj);

  // in cpp
  ClsPrecomp::ClsPrecomp(float alpha_in) {}

  float ClsPrecomp::fastApprox(float x) {
      return x;
  }

  void work(ClsPrecomp& obj) {
      obj.fastApprox(3);
  }
  ```

If you click on the two links, you'll see the generated assembly for these two translation units is fundamentally the same.